# cocos2d-android:how to set text message

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I am new to cocos2d-android. I am trying to set some text on current layer after colliding between two sprites and after some moment text will be vanished. how it possible? plz help.

Comment: thanks your both question they help me so i got this answer for you

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late responce

just call this method in your update method where your `update()` method call in `constructor` with `this.schedule("update");`

and for `addScore()` method your own question [go here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188591/cocos2d-android-how-to-display-score)

```
public void addScore() {
      CCLabel labelScore = CCLabel.makeLabel("" + dead, "DroidSans", 20);
      labelScore.setColor(new ccColor3B(1,1,1));
      labelScore.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(50, 50));
      addChild(labelScore, 11);
      labelScore.setTag(11);
      _labelScores.add(labelScore);
      CCCallFuncN actionMoveDone1 = CCCallFuncN.action(this, "labelFinished");
      CCSequence action = CCSequence.actions(actionMoveDone1);
      labelScore.runAction(action);
}

public void labelFinished(Object sender) { 
    CCLabel label = (CCLabel) sender; 
    if(label.getTag()== 11) 
        _labelScores.remove(label);
    this.removeChild(label, true); 
}
```

and in your update method

```
public void update()
{
     // Here is your code
     addScore();
}
```