# cocos2d-android: how to display score

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

I added CCLabel in my update method to display my game score.
It works well before score raise to 5000. After that logCat shows the messege:

```
02-08 11:47:37.476: E/dalvikvm-heap(4190): 1048576-byte external allocation too large for this process.
02-08 11:47:37.476: E/dalvikvm(4190): Out of memory: Heap Size=14343KB, Allocated=13585KB, Bitmap Size=2078KB
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException......
caused by java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

**My code is:**

```
countScore++ ;
Log.e("total Score:", "" + countScore);
    CCLabel labelScore = CCLabel.makeLabel("" + countScore, "DroidSans", 20);

    labelScore.setColor(new ccColor3B(1,1,1));
    labelScore.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(50, 50));
    addChild(labelScore, 11);
    labelScore.setTag(11);
    _labelScores.add(labelScore);
    CCCallFuncN actionMoveDone1 = CCCallFuncN.action(this, "labelFinished");
    CCSequence action = CCSequence.actions(actionMoveDone1);
    labelScore.runAction(action);
```

How to fix it?

Comment: It looks some memory issue.
There is nothing to do with CCLable.
Just check memory leakage in your code.

Comment: problem with to remove CCLabel properly or anything . any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are creating CCLabel every time when you need.

```
CCLabel labelScore = CCLabel.makeLabel("" + countScore, "DroidSans", 20);
labelScore.setColor(new ccColor3B(1,1,1));
labelScore.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(50, 50));
addChild(labelScore, 11);
labelScore.setTag(11);
```

Don't do that.
Set your ScoreLable as **global variable** and complete its initialization, color setting and positioning in constructor. In your condition use only following code.

```
labelScore.setString("" + countScore);
```

Comment: hi i also want to display score but using this i display only one  level but i want to display score level wise how can i do?

Comment: @user_123 can you show me your code? also explain what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Unless labelFinished does some cleanup that we can't see (you haven't shown us that code), It looks like you are creating 5000 labels.

You should store a single CCLabel as a class member and use setString instead of creating a new label for every score increment.

Better yet, you should use a CCLabelAtlas instead of CCLabel for frequently changing labels (such as scores).

Comment: public void labelFinished(Object sender){
    CCLabel label = (CCLabel) sender;
  
    if(label.getTag()== 11)
    _labelScores.remove(label);
  
    this.removeChild(label, true);
    } this is my labelFinised method @ badgerr

Comment: Fair enough. Did you try CCLabelAtlas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037813/how-to-use-cclistview-in-cocos2d-android here is my question