# How can I use CClistview in COCOS2d Android?

Tags: android, listview, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

I am working on a cocos2d game. In this game, I have to display a score level-wise:

```
==================================================
Level          Score
 1              500
 2              600
 3              900
```

I want to use the cclistview in my game. Does anyone have an idea about cclistview and how it's used in Android cocos2d?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing cocos2d for android and cocos2d-x as same sdk. I don't know of any cclistview in Cocos2d. There is one CCTableView in cocos2d. You can find its implementation in the cocos2d library itself. The package `org.cocos2d.extension.scroll` contains a class CCTableView. You can check its implementation in `org.cocos2d.extension.scroll.tests`.

One other way is to inflate native views from android itself like this:

```
   gameActivity.addContentView(view, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));    //where gameActivity is an instance of my Activity and view is any inflated layout like this

view = (LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.from(gameActivity).inflate(R.layout.some_listview_layout, null);
```

Comment: hi, do you know how to remove it ? I've added a listview, but it's still here when i quit the scene

Comment: you can use view.removeView just like you would do in a normal android app.If you don't have the rootView of the activity you can get it by keeping a reference to the inflated view. something like 
((View)view.getParent()).removeView(view); where view is your inflated view. All in all you'll have to get parent view of the inflated view somehow to remove it. There can be many ways to do that :)